# Iphone UIButton not working in nested UIViews

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

This is so damn simple im sure! Im missing something and im exhausted from trying to fix it. hopefully someone can help.

The Button in CharacterView.m works but the button nested down in CharacterMale.m does not. I'm not using IB everything is done progmatically.
What would cause one button to work and other not?

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 CharacterController.m
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#import "CharacterController.h"
#import "CharacterView.h"

@implementation CharacterController

- (id)init {
    NSLog(@"CharacterController init");
    self = [ super init ];
    if (self != nil) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView {
    [ super loadView ];
    characterView = [ [ CharacterView alloc ] init];
    self.view = characterView;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 CharacterView.m
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#import "CharacterView.h"
#import "CharacterMale.h"

@implementation CharacterView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        characterMale = [ [ CharacterMale alloc ] init];
        [self addSubview: characterMale];

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 200, 100);
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnCharSelect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(ApplyImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [ self addSubview: button ];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
}

-(void)ApplyImage:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"CharacterView button works");
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 CharacterMale.m
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#import "CharacterMale.h"
#import "CharacterController.h"

@implementation CharacterMale

- (id)init {
    self = [ super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"charMale.png"];
        imageView = [[ UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [image release];
        [ self addSubview: imageView ];

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100);
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnCharSelect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(ApplyImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [ self addSubview: button ];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)ApplyImage:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"CharacterMal button works");
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: What do you mean your buttons stop working? Are they enabled but don't call the selectors or can't you click them at all? Also how do you hook them up to the selectors? If you are using IB, check the outlets and connections

Comment: I can't click the button at all, nothing happens. If I take the View class the button is located in out of its parent View the button the works. Im not using IB. I connect the button using: [button addTarget:self action:@selector(ApplyImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; Again it works fine when its not nested into another view.

Comment: I posted all 3 classes. Can someone help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

FINALLY!!!!!!

I had to init all the views with initWithFrame and pass in valid frame rects. Init should be used with controllers and initWithFrame passing rects for UIViews!!!!

```
characterView = [ [ CharacterView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)]; 
then 
characterMale = [ [ CharacterMale alloc ] initWithFrame:frame];
```

Comment: @Roger Because others might have the same problem. You don't just delete a question when it's resolved...

Answer (score 17):

Another thing to consider is that `UIButton` subviews that have been added a `UIImageView` don't work at all. You need to create a `UIView` that you add both the image view and the buttons to.

This is probably because interaction is turned off by default on image views, but I've not checked this.

Comment: Kay, Thank you for the advice. I set UIImageView suerInteractionEnabled to yes and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Does the new view accept user interaction?  In other words, is userInteractionEnabled enabled on the view "Characters"?

Comment: I thought I had read userInteractionEnabled by default is YES. I would think in this situation I would make userInteractionEnabled = NO for the CharactersView class. I think this view is somehow blocking the button in my CharactersMale class. In any case I tried and no difference.

Comment: I have a view that contains a bunch of buttons.  I addView a new view with a few of its own buttons over the ones that were there.  All buttons work, including the ones between the first layer and the second (top) layer.  So I you should have no problems nesting buttons.

But if I turn off userInteraction in the superLayer, all buttons stop working.  If I only turn off userInteraction in the top layer, it only disabled the button on that layer.

Keep at it.  I bet you'll find a simple error or so.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when tried to add the button during the initialization of an UIView with a frame of CGRectZero:

```
@implementation SomeView
...
- (id)initWithTitleImage:(UIImage *) newTitleImage {
  // BROKEN: frame with CGRectZero.
  self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
  if (self) {
    UIButton *someButton = ...;
    [self addSubview someButton];
  }
}
```

Once I changed the frame to a proper rectangle, the button worked:

```
@implementation SomeView
...
- (id)initWithTitleImage:(UIImage *) newTitleImage {
  // WORKING: frame with proper CGRect.
  self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
  if (self) {
    UIButton *someButton = ...;
    [self addSubview someButton];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had luck with a selector for a UIButton created in drawRect by using `UIControlEventTouchDown` instead of the popular `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was caused because, the origin of the button frame was bigger then the parent frame.