# UIButton selector doesn't work in nested UIViews

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I have this problem driving me crazy. I have spent decades to figure it out why this is happening.

I have a `UIScrollView` as **scrollView**  in a `UIView`. In this scrollView, i have three different `UIView`s which are created  at runtime. In one of these three `UIView`s, i create a button .Here is my code to do that.

```c
        UIButton *buttonLike = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect ] ;
        buttonLike.frame =CGRectMake(scrollViewWidth +200, 30,36, 16);
        buttonLike.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"like.png"];
        [buttonLike addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonLikePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] ;
```

**scrollViewWidth** is a constant defined and initialized as well.
And,i add this **buttonLike** as a subview in one of the `UIViews`. But,no matter what i do , **buttonLikePressed** method doesn't invoke.
I've searched this issue and came up with these solutions.
 [Iphone UIButton not working in nested UIViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818739/iphone-uibutton-not-working-in-nested-uiviews)
[iPhone SDK 2: UIButton not working in nested views loaded from nib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957671/iphone-sdk-2-uibutton-not-working-in-nested-views-loaded-from-nib-file?rq=1)
 They described the same issue. But,as a solution they initialize their views using 
`-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect` method. Well,i've already initialized my **UIViews** using  `initWithFrame`method. Do u guys have any idea how i can resolve this problem ?

Thank you all

Comment: How are you init all these views with initWithFrame ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does your button even react to a touch? Does it highlight when pressed?

Because it sounds like you are adding this button to a view outside of that view's bounds which prevents touches being propagated to the button. You either have to increase that view's width to `scrollViewWidth + 200 + 36`or more or you need to put the button inside view's bounds. Show us how you create that view that you add a button to.

Comment: UIView *viewNewsProperties = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];   [viewNewsProperties addSubView :buttonLike ] ; And I add this view to scrollView.

Comment: I guess your scrollView is also 320 pixels wide? So you are adding a button to 320 + 200 which is 520 pixels from the left border of viewNewsProperties and which places it far out of its 320 pixel bounds. You need to make viewNewsProperties's frame wider (like `CGRectMake(0, 0, 556, 60)`).

Comment: You are welcome. The first thing to do when you have a problem like this is set a different background color on "non-responsive" view's superview and its superview and so on. This lets you see if something is outside of bounds without calculating it in your head. For example, set green background on scrollView, red on viewNewsProperties and blue on button and you will see that blue is outside of red which is bad :)

Comment: @FilipRadelic You are right! .. But ideally `UIView` should clip that button if parent frame doest fits.

Comment: @Jack sure, you can make views clip to bounds and the button wouldn't be visible. You can also use the view debugger in Xcode these days which would help in both cases :)

Answer (score 0):

You should init all these views with initWithFrame and you should pass in valid frame rects.
Try this and you like button will work !

Comment: I already init my views with initWithFrame ,and i'm pretty sure i pass valid frame rects .

Answer (score 0):

I think that the UIButton should get the touch event first but I had a similar issue where the buttons weren't getting pressed.  What I ended up doing was running a check in the touchesBegan method of the parent view to see if it touched around the area of the button.  This was also very helpful in my case because I was able to specify a larger area so the buttons were easier to press.  Then I just fired off the touch event for the button.

Another way which would be much easier would be setting isUserInteractionEnabled to false for the parent views of the button, of course only if you dont need them to respond to touches.

These are just ideas to hack around your problem, not sure how to actually solve it.

Comment: Oh just noticed something that might be the underlying cause - your button sizes are small, I think they have to be at least 44x44 or something to be able to work.  Or at least thats what Apple recommends for minimum button size.

Comment: I made them bigger,but still doesn't work. The second way u mentioned isn't a good way for me like u explained the reason.

Comment: Maybe the parent view is clipping the button.  Try setting clipSubviews to NO in the parent views.  Can you actually see the button on the screen and just can't press it or is it not showing up at all?