# UIButton doesn't work in UIScrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have `UIScrollview` and view. In view I have `UIButton` which doesn't work, if I have `UIButton` in UIScrollview works. I have User Interaction Enabled on both.

[image]

for button I have this method:

```
- (IBAction)search
{
    NSLog(@"SEARCH");
}
```

[image]

Whatever I give to the view doesn't work.

**I solve the problem. View was not properly configured (Constraints in autolayout)**

Comment: is that method connected to your button?

Comment: Yes it is (Touch up inside)

Comment: are the button events send to file owner?

Comment: does the `Connections Inspector` show that the button has an action?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
  {
       return ![view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]];
  }
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When an `UIButton` doesn't send the message to the `IBAction`receiver is because the button `view` is not contained in the `superview.frame`

Try it setting a `backgroundColor` to the `superview`

Take a look there: [UIButton selector doesn't work in nested UIViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953402/uibutton-selector-doesnt-work-in-nested-uiviews)

Comment: BackgroundColor is default. I try  [scroll addSubview:view1]; [view1 addSubview:searchbtn]; and still nothing.

Comment: I know is default background color. So set to view1 a different backgroundColor to see if the UIButton is out-of-view1. However, try to log the `view1.frame` and `searchbtn.frame`

Comment: I set different color and when I run the simulator is still the default color. Button is in the view.

Comment: Well, if the color is still the default, there is a problem with your view. Why, if you create the view via Interface Builder, do you do the `addSubview:` via code?

Comment: Apparently not been properly configured Constraints in autolayout